# Does LED thermal need to be isolated from GND in this case?

Tags: led, dc-dc-converter, thermal, heatsink

I'm designing a small LED device which is powered by a battery.

The case of the device is acting as the GND line between the battery and the LED driver, but it is also acting as the heatsink for the LED.

Between the LED cathode, feedback pin and GND there is a sense resistor. Will I need to electrically (but not thermally) isolate the thermal pad of the LED to the case of the device in my design?

Simplified schematics below:
[image]

Comment: Which LED?  A datasheet would be very helpful.

Comment: in fact, the LED datasheet would exactly tell you whether the thermal pad is isolated or not – and that's all you'd need to answer this question.

Comment: Cree XP-L. https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/ds-XPL.pdf, it says "electrically neutral thermal path" which answers my question?

Comment: @Han, you should edit that link into the question as it's essential information that shouldn't be hidden in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the [XLamp datasheet](https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/ds-XPL.pdf) says the parts have an "electrically neutral thermal path" - that is, the thermal pad (for the heat sink) is not connected to the electrical parts of the LED.

For the intended circuit in the question, the thermal pad on the LED can be connected to the ground plane of the PCB.